# How to convert timestamp to html date input field value PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

In my code, here is how i convert html date field values to unix timestamp before inserting to MySQL db which works fine:

```
//HTML Code:
<div class="form-group">
From:
<input type="date" name="dateFrom" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
To:
<input type="date" name="dateTo" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required/>
</div>

//PHP Code to convert to Time Stamp:
<?php $post->unix_stamp = strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']);
$post->unix_stamp_ex = strtotime($_POST['dateTo']);
$post->save(); ?>
```

How do i convert the unix timestamp back to html input date value for editing? What i've tried:

```
<input type="date" name="dateTo" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",$post->unix_stamp_ex); ?>" required/>
```

Where $post->unix_stamp_ex is the unix timestamp value. (doesn't work for me, shows dd/mm/yyyy instead). My problem is how to get the underlying value, to display in the date input so users can edit it

Comment: Value and display are not the same thing. Date inputs *show* the value based on locale. The *underlying value* is in `'Y-m-d'`, always. If you inspect your element in the browser, you'll see that the value has a different format than what is shown.

Comment: @El_Vanja Got it, but my problem is how to get the underlying value, to display in the date input so users can edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your input is showing a placeholder 'dd/mm/yyyy' is because it cannot read the format you gave it. It can't work with time, so you need to remove it from your code:

```
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',$post->unix_stamp_ex); ?>"
```

This will show the date in the input.

Also, mind that the displayed value will differ from the actual value format, as per my comment and RoussKS' answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla Developer docs for input type date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

> The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

[edit]
Just noticed the comment response, was typing as El_Vanja commented
[/edit]

Comment: My problem is how to get the underlying value, to display in the date input so users can see and edit it

Comment: Master_Osaro, follow @El_Vanja answer, that should solve your case.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I am able to convert the database string back to readable date time using the following method.

#### Solutions

```
$databaseTime = '2020-03-22 09:45:48';
$date = strtotime($databaseTime);

echo "DatabaseTime: " . $databaseTime . "<br>";
echo "Date in epoch: ".$date."<br>";
echo "Readable date: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date)."<br>";
```

#### Results

https://prnt.sc/rkmleq